# What could go wrong in redefining Power to act on functions?

Tags: built-in-symbols

Inspired by a tweet (from a locked account, unfortunately, so I can't link it), we can get notation like $\cos^2(x)$ to work in Mathematica in general:

```
Unprotect[Power];
Power[f_, n_][x___] := Power[f[x], n];
```

While this works by entering `n` as a superscript (with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd>), to get expressions like `Cos^2[x]` to work, which parse by default as `Power[Cos, 2[x]]`, we could also include the somewhat more restrictve

```
Power[f_, (n_?NumericQ)[x___]] := Power[f[x], n]
```

(Note that this doesn't account for expressions like `Cos^n[x]`, though.)

Weirdly, so far, I can't think of anything this would break, since—as far as I can tell—`Power[f_, n_]` is never otherwise expected to appear as the head of some other expression, and neither is something which is `NumericQ`. It seems like despite seeming terribly irresponsible, this might...actually be a convenient choice.

Is there any chaos this could cause that I'm not thinking of?

One potential gotcha would be the difference between `Cos^2[x]` and `Cos^n[x]`. That makes me think that it's best to omit definition 2 and simply require parentheses or superscript notation.

Comment: It doesn't quite achieve my interpretation of the desired notation. See `Cos^2[x] // FullForm` --> `Power[Cos, 2[x]]` for instance.  (Needs parentheses.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 If you enter `2` as a superscript, with ctrl + ^, it works!

Comment: @MichaelE2 However, it is possible to get `Cos^2[x]` to work similarly—updated as such!

Comment: True. I meant it only as a minor quibble. (Shift-6 `^` is how I usually enter `Power`, unless I'm typesetting text.) -- I don't know of any serious problem. If a program mistakenly tried to apply an expression instead of a function, for instance, `(x^2)[3]`, it might make the bug harder to track down.

Comment: Right, gotcha! Me too. I just thought it was nifty when I saw it, and was surprised when I realized that such an apparently big change to a built-in didn't seem to break anything.